# Best alternative to passing std::optional<std::shared_ptr<Data>> as parameter?

Tags: c++

I have some existing code that in many places passes

```
boost::optional<std::shared_ptr<Data>>
```

as a parameter to a function.

The function itself does not need "ownership" of the function so copying the shared pointer is both inefficient and misleading. If it wasn't for the 'optional' I would change this to take a `Data const&` instead and deference the shared pointer in the call.

However I can't do this with optional as you can't have an optional reference.

I've seen alternative of just passing a raw pointer instead of a reference as it exactly fits the semantics required. However objections are sometimes raised to using raw pointers rightly or wrongly.

Is there a better way to pass this value other than just as a `Data const *` that ideally works in C++11 but any thoughts are required.

Closing and Linking to other answers are welcome if this is a duplicate, but the other answers I've seen tend to just say that optional<T&> is wrong or to use a T* without really talking about best style or alternatives.

Edit: Changed to boost::optional instead of std::optional as that is what is being used as the codebase is for the moment C++11

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using raw pointers as long as the ownership is handled by some form of smart pointer

Comment: I'm unsure what's wrong with a raw pointer? It's same as a reference, but with nullability, which is exactly what you want, no?

Comment: what does the function do when the optional is empty? Perhaps you dont need to call the function when the optional is empty? (your wish to pass a `Data const&` suggests that this is the case)

Comment: "ideally works in C++11" ? `std::optional` is C++17

Comment: In many cases there is an optional additional parameter that is usually not provided but can be (So still need to call it when the parameter is optnull).

Sorry the code is using a boost optional which works in C++11 but I tried to simplify the question thus causing confusion over C++11/17, apologies.

Personally I think nothing is wrong with raw pointer here and is the best solution but wanted to see if there were any preferred alternatives as various standards I have to work against strongly prefer no raw pointers, so I wanted to be sure there was no better answer.

Comment: What standards exactly? I'm sorry, but this line of thinking just *feels* wrong. A raw pointer works. Unless you can point out a specific issue with it, *or* your style guide explicitly bans them, just use it.

Comment: raw owning pointers should be banned, passing by raw pointer when a reference can be used is not nice, and there are more way to misuse them, but banning raw pointers completely is rather exxagerated and misses the point.

Comment: please note that comments are shortlived and clarification from comments should be incorporated in the question. In the question there is still the discrepancy between `std::optional` and C++11, you should edit to clarify that

Comment: Agree 100% on the raw pointers thing, coding standards say use smart pointers instead of raw pointers instead of talking about owndership. That needs to change.

Comment: 90% of what I see is measured advice that raw pointers shouldn't be used for ownership. But there is a body of "Raw pointers are dead!" giddiness. They're not. I would put money on `shared_ptr<>` being the most over used class in the whole of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is nothing wrong with passing a raw pointer provided:

1. the function does not store the pointer for later use (takes/shares ownership)
2. passing nullptr to the function is meaningful

But lets look deeper into your type:

```
boost::optional<std::shared_ptr<Data>>
```

So this can be a shared pointer or none. And a shared pointer can also be a nullptr. So there are 3 ways to call your function:

```
foo(boost::none);
foo(boost::make_optional(std::shared_ptr()); // nullptr
foo(boost::make_optional(std::make_shared(data)));
```

Does your function really make a distinction between `none` and `nullptr`. That exists but is rather rare.

If not then the optional is unnecessary.

PS: Don't forget to check the `std::shared_ptr` before use. I really wish there would be a `std::shared_ref`.

Answer (score 2):

As you are considering to change the function to take a `Data const&` argument, I assume the function is doing nothing when the optional is empty. If that is the case you can simply not call the function when there is no value:

```
#include <optional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {};

int bar(const foo& f, int y) {
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    return 42;
}

template <typename F,typename T>
void call_if(std::optional<std::shared_ptr<T>> t,F f){
    if (t) {
        f(**t);
    } else { 
        std::cout << "not called\n";
    }
}


int main() {
    std::optional<std::shared_ptr<foo>> x;
    int res = 0;
    call_if(x,[&res](const foo& f){ res = bar(f,123);});
    x = std::make_shared<foo>();
    call_if(x,[&res](const foo& f){ res = bar(f,123);});
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MTaqnoKsd)

---

If you do want to call the function in any case consider to pass a optional reference. You are right that `std::optional<T&>` is not correct,  but consider ([from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional))

> There are no optional references; a program is ill-formed if it instantiates an optional with a reference type. Alternatively, an optional of a std::reference_wrapper of type T may be used to hold a reference.

Though you still need to explicitly check if the optional does contain a value to perform the conversion:

```
#include <optional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo {};
using opt_t = std::optional<std::shared_ptr<foo>>;
using opt_ref_t = std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<foo>>;

void bar(opt_ref_t t) {
    if (t)  std::cout << "hello\n";
    else std::cout << "empty\n";
}

opt_ref_t get_ref(opt_t t) {
    if (t) return {**t};
    else return {};
}

int main() {
    std::optional<std::shared_ptr<foo>> x;
    bar(get_ref(x));
    x = std::make_shared<foo>();
    bar(get_ref(x));
}
```

---

Last but not least, `std::optional<std::shared_ptr<Data>>` is a rather odd type to begin with. A `std::shared_ptr` can already be "emtpy", there is no point in wrapping it in a `std::optional`. I suppose this is due to legacy code and you cannot change it. If you can, I suggest to change it.

Moreoever, there is nothing wrong with passing a raw pointer rather than `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` when `nullptr` is a valid input for a function:

```
void bar(foo* f) {
    if (f) { 
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, some interesting options there.

And yes, this is legacy code I'm trying to improve one small step at a time, starting with not passing shared_ptr by value everywhere even when no ownership is needed. Perhaps this needs a bigger change in one update :)